# Commutator of the product of two finite families of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G_i)_{i\in[1,n]}$, $(H_i)_{i\in[1,n]}$  be two finite families of groups. Is it true that
$$\left[\prod_i G_i,\prod_i H_i\right]=\prod_i\left[G_i,H_i\right]?$$

The inclusion $\left[\prod_i G_i,\prod_i H_i\right]\subset\prod_i\left[G_i,H_i\right]$ is easy to demonstrate. I am having difficulty proving the other direction. For $i\in[1,n]$, let 
$$\iota_i:[G_i,H_i]\rightarrow\prod_i [G_i,H_i]$$
be the canonical injection. My idea was to show that $\text{Im}(\iota_i)\subset\left[\prod_i G_i,\prod_i H_i\right]$. But I'm not sure if this will work.

Do I need to assume some extra condition in order to make this work?

Comment: I'd start by looking at induction on $n$. This is just a hunch . . .

Comment: Your question is confusing and doesn't make much sense as stated. The commutator operation $[G,H]$ is ordinarily not defined on pairs of abstract groups $G,H$. It is instead defined on pairs of subgroups $G,H < \Gamma$ of some given group $\Gamma$. Did you intend for your groups $G_i,H_i$ all to be subgroups of some given group? Or did you instead have some other meaning of $[G,H]$?